# An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

I am getting an error when using AVAudioPlayer in Iphone. i got this error sometime not every time. error is :

> An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer

Code which i am using for playing a file :

```
NSString *soundPath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"abc" ofType:@"m4a"];
NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
NSError *error;

AVAudioPlayer *theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:&error];
[theAudio setDelegate:self];
[theAudio setNumberOfLoops:0];
if(theAudio == nil)
{
    NSLog([error description]);
}
else
{
    [theAudio play];
}
```

can anyone tell me how can i solve this issue.

Comment: are you using `AVAudioPlayer` more then once in your app? or this is the only code you use for only once in your app?

Comment: yes i am using more than once.

Comment: so this warning is regarding that you might have to create a global instance within your class and re use the instance of audio player that might stop this warning.